# Are there any example or resources or even framework which consists of Asp.net MVP + Sandcastle + TDD/Nunit + Fitnesse?

Tags: tdd, frameworks, asp.net-2.0, fitnesse, sandcastle

our dev team is currently using asp.net 2.0 and after a lot of browsing and cross site referencing i found that the new in thing is the asp.net MVC but found that there's a few things that it can't do such as support asp.net controls, view state.

i'm not sure what are the other limitation besides the total change of paradigm where each page will now link to the controller which will be linked to a certain view. so in order to make the learning curve to be less steep, i wanted to pick up on MVP first as i think by just being able to take out the application and domain layer out and make them testable is already a big help to our total process without being too much of a hassle.

after more browsing around, i find that the ndoc is a bit outdated now and is being replaced by sandcastle which has an additional add in call docproject so that should covers the auto generation of the documentation in the codes very well.

and to handle the acceptance test, i find this tool call fitnesse which is based on FIT which should helps.

so being totally new to all of this, i'm wondering if this is a good process overall to have this tool in to cover our team's development process. and if there's other sample/resources/framework out there which covers all of these steps and does a better job than trying to piece in the gap by using several tools, i.e. a framework?

1. basically my question is is my
   overall process above well covered
   by the tools that i've researched?
2. and is there a better way to do the
       asp.net tdd + auto doc generation +
       acceptance testing?

any advice/feedback is appreciated.
thanks!! :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, ASP.NET MVC with NUnit and FitNesse are reasonable choices for an 'agile' approach.  Just not sure where auto-doc generation fits into this.  Will anyone read this generated documentation or will they just look at the code?  If you haven't read it yet, get Robert Martin's 'Clean Code' for some good tips on how to make code maintainable and understandable without lots of comments and generated documents.

Comment: well the team was saying that we lack API level documentation and i thought the auto doc generation will cover this part nicely.

Comment: Agreed, additionally the Fitnesse tests themselves should be all the documentation you need!